# Sylius Remove fields in Extended model

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am trying to customize the models of sylius to suit my project requirements.

I want to remove some of the model fields from the database tables .

```
Eg:
sylius_address has

street
company
```

i want to remove those and add below

```
bldg no
subarea
```

I have gone through the documentation, it showcases how to add new fields, but i would want to remove existing and then add new fields.

Comment: It is a Doctine extended models limitation. You can make fork of Sylius, remove/modify fields from it, and set fork URL into a needed project `composer.json`

Comment: @Dr.X if i have make changes in Core Sylius, would it not break if i want to upgrade to next version of Sylius, which is due on 1st June 2018

Comment: theoretically you can then update your fork when you need even from Github UI and receive actual version of Sylius